# Polymer CLI multiple elements on a page and duplicate calls

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x

So I'm new to polymer and decided to take a look at polymer 2.0. I found the Polymer CLI and decided to create a couple of custom elements. I've managed to get them rendering on a page but I'm hoping to try to better understand the best practices for having multiple elements on the same page.

Right now my current project structure looks like this.

```
  index.html - used to display the elements
  elements
  ->first-element
     -> bower_components
     -> demo -> index.html
     -> test -> first-element_test.html
     -> bower.json
     -> first-element.html
     -> index.html
     -> polymer.json
  ->second-element
     -> bower_components
     -> demo -> index.html
     -> test -> second-element_test.html
     -> bower.json
     -> second-element.html
     -> index.html
     -> polymer.json
```

I have a index.html template file that is importing the two elements to display.

```
inside index.html file:

<link rel="import" href="elements/first-element/first-element.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="elements/second-element/second-element.html"/>

<first-element></first-element>
<second-element></second-element>
```

Now I am able to see them rendering on front but I had a couple question about best practices for multiple elements on the same page and maybe not having calls to duplicate. Currently in both element html files by default each element has it own `bower_components` and they both import `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">` in their `.html` file. So when I render both elements on the page you can see duplicated requests with all files associated with the `polymer-element.html`.

My question is, is there a cleaner way to do this? or is this how polymer handles multiple elements on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your elements, and start building the application, polymer-cli will analyze your sources and deduplicate your imports when you build a bundle. You will then end up with single file that contains all dependencies in one place.

Also worth mentioning you should have a single `bower_components` directory, subsequent imports to same resource should not fire requests again.

I have a structure like this:

```
-- bower_components
-- node_modules
-- src
    -- elem1
    ...
    -- elemN
```

where elem1 will import `<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">` like that.

Comment: Is there a way to have all element components point to the bower_components folder if I create the directory inside the root "elements" folder? I've tried doing it but I seem to be having issues with being able to target to that parent folder path when trying import it inside the first-element.html.

Comment: I always end up with single `bower components` directory (containing external dependencies) in my projects, your application specific components should be relative to that dir.
I've updated my answer with example directory structure.